# choose the best php / mysql syntax from the various of format?

Tags: php

I come across with various type of format, here are them

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Persons SET Age=36
WHERE FirstName='Peter' AND LastName='Griffin'");
```

and

```
SELECT ALL FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id
```

..and about mysql_query, it works without the $con parameter, explain? thanks

Comment: The second query is a prepared statement with PDO. And yes, `mysql_query` works without the addition parameter. But you should really be looking at PDO/mysqli since `mysql_*` is depreciated.

Comment: The second select statement is using a prepared statement and bind variables; something that it will be very useful for you to learn about as it's highly recommended to protect your application against SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 1):

> it works without the $con parameter, explain?

The former code is **`MySQLi`** and the latter is a **`PDO`** Statement.

Getting started with [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Getting started with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

[PDO vs MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query detects the last connection to a database.